# Elasticsearch : find all mapping types of a given index using the Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client

I basically want to retrieve all types of a given elasticsearch index using the java client. I'm working with elasticsearch 5.4.1.

I already succeeded to get the list of indices with this code :

```java
indices = client.admin()
    .indices()
    .getIndex(new GetIndexRequest())
    .actionGet()
    .getIndices();
```

So now, let's say I want all types of the first index, how can I manage to do so ?

This is what I already tried but it's not working. I can't resolve the ObjectObjectCursor dependency (com.carrotsearch.hppc.cursors.ObjectObjectCursor).

```java
try {
    GetMappingsResponse res = clientTest.admin().indices().getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest().indices(myIndex)).get();
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData> mapping = res.mappings().get(myIndex);
    for (ObjectObjectCursor<String, MappingMetaData> c : mapping) {
        typeList.add(c);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: which client r u using ?

Comment: I use ```TransportClient```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `ObjectObjectCursor` class but you can do it with simple iterator, e.g.:

```
GetMappingsResponse res = client.admin().indices().getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest().indices("<index_name>")).get();
ImmutableOpenMap<String,ImmutableOpenMap<String,MappingMetaData>> mappings = res.getMappings();
System.out.println(mappings);
ImmutableOpenMap<String,MappingMetaData> mapping = mappings.get("<type_name>");
for(Iterator<MappingMetaData> iterator = mapping.valuesIt() ; iterator.hasNext();) {
    MappingMetaData metaData = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(metaData.getSourceAsMap());
}
```

Although this just prints the mappings, you can use it to access different components and their types.

Comment: Well, dunno why I didn't think about it and I tried in the first place with ObjectObjectCursor. But thanks !